# Why `&=` does inplace in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], data=[True, False, True])
d = {}
d[1] = mask
mask &= False
print(d[1])
```

I thought d[1] will be still [True, False, True], but actually it becomes [False, False, False]

Why does `&=` do inplace?

if I change to `mask = mask & False`, then d[1] won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas dataframes are pointers, `x=` is in-place operators in Python. So when you do:

```
mask &= False
```

you perform the operation in-place on the object that `mask` is pointing to.

However

```
mask = mask & False
```

is different. `mask & False` creates a new object, and `mask = new_object` points `mask` to the new object, while `d[1]` points to the object that `mask` previously pointed to. Therefore, after the above command, `mask` and `d[1]` are two different objects. You can verify that with `id(d[1]) == id(mask)` before and after the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It is assign and calculation, it will change the same `object`

```
#mask &= False

mask = mask & False
```

Fix

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], data=[True, False, True])
d = {}
d[1] = mask.copy() # add copy here
mask &= False 
print(d[1])
       0
1   True
2  False
3   True
```

More detail

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], data=[True, False, True])
d = {}
d[1] = mask
id(mask),id(d[1]) # same object 
Out[482]: (2558679905288, 2558679905288)


d[1] = mask.copy()
id(mask),id(d[1]) # diff object so change one another one stay the same 
Out[484]: (2558679850184, 2558674488968)
```

Comment: I think my question is more about `why`? Why pandas make `&=` a kind of inplace

Comment: @JacksonTale it is change the same object &= not assign to the new one , try with mask=mask & False